# Coudl not find video device with name [integrated camera]amoung source devices of type video

Tags: python, io, webrtc, aiortc

Im testing aiortc becouse i wanna stream webcam audio and video to browser but when im trying to run webcam.py i get I/O error I/O error: 'video=Integrated Camera'

**[CODE IS HERE on github](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/blob/main/examples/webcam/webcam.py)**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\New folder\env\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_protocol.py", line 422, in _handle_request
    resp = await self._request_handler(request)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\New folder\env\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_app.py", line 499, in _handle
    resp = await handler(request)
  File "webcam.py", line 69, in offer
    audio, video = create_local_tracks(args.play_from)
  File "webcam.py", line 36, in create_local_tracks
    "video=Integrated Camera", format="dshow", options=options
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\New folder\env\lib\site-packages\aiortc\contrib\media.py", line 238, in __init__
    self.__container = av.open(file=file, format=format, mode="r", options=options)
  File "av\container\core.pyx", line 355, in av.container.core.open
  File "av\container\core.pyx", line 226, in av.container.core.Container.__cinit__
  File "av\container\core.pyx", line 258, in av.container.core.Container.err_check
  File "av\error.pyx", line 336, in av.error.err_check
av.error.OSError: [Errno 5] I/O error: 'video=Integrated Camera'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okey if you get this error you need to check names of your devices with ffmpeg
**windows**

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

**linux**

```
v4l2-ctl --list-devices
```

and get correct names for your devices and change them accordingly